# Title of the document on the same page as the document

Tags: formatting, titles

I want to achieve the following look:

[image: The look]

If I use `\title`, the title will take up the whole page, if I use `\section` it will be numerated.

This is the code which i am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}

\section{\fontsize{20}{8}\selectfont \centering Title}

content bla bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried with another documentclass, like `article`? Please add a small, but compilable, test document to your question so we can which class etc. you use.

Comment: The title depends in the document class and options. With article classes like the standard class `article` or KOMA-Script class `scrartcl` usually title heads are the default. But using class option `titlepage` you can switch to a title page. On the other hand report and book classes like the standard classes `book` and `report` or the KOMA-Script classes `scrbook` and `scrreprt` usually default to title pages. But you can change this also using option `notitlepage` resp. `titlepage=false`. For better help I would need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: BTW: Using commands like `\fontsize` or `\centering` as an argument of `\section` is not really a good idea. Just add a `\tableofcontents` or use `\pagestyle{headings}` and you'd see why. If you want to re-configure the section title you should use a package like `titlesec` or a configurable class like `scrartcl`.

Comment: letters 20pt high placed on lines 8pt apart????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `article` the default is already a title head:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

content bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, not the whole page is occupied by the title.

If you don't want an author and date, just use empty arguments:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

content bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]